# Does it make sense to configure the web server to deny obviously malicious requests?

Tags: web-application, webserver

I have a Ruby on Rails app behind Nginx. Every once in a while I see requests like `GET /phpmyadmin` or `GET /wp-login.php`. Since I don't have those tools installed, it's obvious that those are from someone trying to get into my site.

Does it make sense to add a couple rules to my Nginx config to automatically return 403 to those requests and not bother the primary app with having to return 404?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide us with info like, is it a requests from a crawler/bot or just some random visitors are requesting this pages that does not exist ?

Comment: I've been debating if I should create a rule to add IPs that request things like these to fail2ban.  Trying to hack my site? We don't need your traffic.  Is this unreasonable?

Comment: @mrSotirow Judging by the user agents, they're people. But then again, it's not a good indication.

Comment: @user10489 IIRC there are situations (NAT?) where you can have multiple people behind one IP address.

Comment: @art-solopov Its possible that someone is trying to find a login page or something similar to bruteforce.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange requests to web server](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40291/strange-requests-to-web-server)

Comment: @mentallurg: I don't see this as a duplicate, because this is a more specific question on how this kind of request are best handled in a reverse proxy setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denying *obvious* malicious requests having actual payloads like SQL injections or XSS attempts would be building a *web application firewall* (WAF), which is a useful *defence-in-depth strategy* against unknown or unpatched vulnerabilities. Denying requests that would already result in `404` errors does not add any security from that perspective, but it might still be a good idea to do it on the *reverse proxy* as it reduces the load on the backend server(s).

It does not otherwise matter whether you reply with `404` or `403` but using a different status code you give free hints on what you have denied manually. Consider moving the task to the reverse proxy but continuing using the status code `404`.

Also, take a look at the [`proxy_cache_valid`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_valid) directive; if appropriate, you could e.g. cache all `404` responses for an hour with `proxy_cache_valid 404 1h;`.